# How to overwrite php _() function

Tags: php

Is there anyway to overwrite php's **_($msgid)** function ?? 
i see that function located in php core gettext.php

i'm using `php7`

i have tried to

```
function _($msg)
{   
    echo $msg;
}
```

geting error

> Cannot redeclare _()

Screenshot for **gettext.php** from **eclipse**

[image]

Comment: *php core **gettext.php*** ?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/140584/how-to-remove-the-php-gettext-extension

Comment: @HankyPanky i updated my question with screenshot. Im using Eclispe and when i control click on _( it reffers me to that file i understood it as it is some core php file

Comment: @Phil you mean only the way is disable php's gettext module and then write my on functions instead yes ?